# C program days between two dates -- output slightly too high?

Tags: c

This C program for my college course is supposed to find the number of days between two dates.  It works for the most part, but the output is usually just a few days too high when month1 and month2 are different.  Also, months which have 31 days don't seem to be recognized as such, resulting in the "Invalid month and day combination" error message when "31" is entered as the day.  I'm not at all sure why either of these problems are occurring.  Thanks in advance for your help guys!

```
// Calculates the number of calendar days between any two dates in history (beginning with 1/1/1).

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void date(int *month1, int *day1, int *year1, int *month2, int *day2, int *year2);
void leap(int year1, int year2, int *leap1, int *leap2);

int main(void)
{
  int month1, day1, year1, month2, day2, year2, leap1, leap2;

  date(&month1, &day1, &year1, &month2, &day2, &year2);
  leap(year1, year2, &leap1, &leap2);

  if(year1 == year2)
  {
    int i, total = 0;

    if(month1 == month2)                            // Total days if month1 == month2
    {
      total = day2 - day1;
      printf("There are %d days between the two dates.", total);
    }
    else
    {
      if(month1 == 1||3||5||7||8||10)         // Days remaining in first month
        total = 31 - day1;
      else if(month1 == 4||6||9||11)
        total = 30 - day1;
      else
      {
        if(leap1 == 1)
          total = 29 - day1;
        else
          total = 28 - day1;
      }

      for(i = month1 + 1; i < month2; i++)    // Days remaining between dates (excluding last month)
      {
        if(i == 3||5||7||8||10)
          total += 31;
        else if(i == 4||6||9||11)
          total += 30;
        else
        {
          if(leap1 == 1)
            total += 29;
          else
            total += 28;
        }
      }

      total += day2;                          // Final sum of days between dates (including last month)

      printf("There are %d days between the two dates.", total);
    }
  }
  else                                                    // If year1 != year2 ...
  {
    int i, total, century1 = ((year1 / 100) + 1) * 100, falseleap = 0;

    if(month1 == 1||3||5||7||8||10||12)             // Days remaining in first month
      total = 31 - day1;
    else if(month1 == 4||6||9||11)
      total = 30 - day1;
    else
    {
      if(leap1 == 1)
        total = 29 - day1;
      else
        total = 28 - day1;
    }

    for(i = month1 + 1; i <= 12; i++)               // Day remaining in first year
    {
      if(i == 3||5||7||8||10||12)
        total += 31;
      else if(i == 4||6||9||11)
        total += 30;
      else
      {
        if(leap1 == 1)
          total += 29;
        else
          total += 28;
      }
    }

    for(i = 1; i < month2; i++)                     // Days remaining in final year (excluding last month)
    {
      if(i == 1||3||5||7||8||10)
        total += 31;
      else if(i == 4||6||9||11)
        total += 30;
      else
      {
        if(leap2 == 1)
          total += 29;
        else
          total += 28;
      }
    }

    int leapcount1 = year1 / 4;                     // Leap years prior to and including first year
    int leapcount2 = year2 / 4;                     // Leap years prior to and NOT including final year
    if(year2 % 4 == 0)
      leapcount2 -= 1;

    int leaptotal = leapcount2 - leapcount1;        // Leap years between dates

    for(i = century1; i < year2; i += 100)          // "False" leap years (divisible by 100 but not 400)
    {
      if((i % 400) != 0)
        falseleap += 1;
    }

    total += 365 * (year2 - year1 - 1) + day2 + leaptotal - falseleap;      // Final calculation
    printf("There are %d days between the two dates.", total);
  }
  return 0;
}

void date(int *month1, int *day1, int *year1, int *month2, int *day2, int *year2)
{
  for(;;)                                                         // Infinite loop (exited upon valid input)
  {
    int fail = 0;
    printf("Enter first date: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", month1, day1, year1);
    if(*month1 < 1 || *month1 > 12)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for month.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*day1 < 1 || *day1 > 31)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for day.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*year1 < 1)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for year.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if((*month1 == 4||6||9||11) && *day1 > 30)
    {
      printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*month1 == 2)
    {
      if(*year1 % 4 == 0)
      {
        if(*year1 % 100 == 0)
        {
          if(*year1 % 400 == 0 && *day1 > 29)
          {
            printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
            fail += 1;
          }
          if(*year1 % 400 != 0 && *day1 > 28)
          {
            printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
            fail += 1;
          }
        }
        if(*year1 % 100 != 0 && *day1 > 29)
        {
          printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
          fail += 1;
        }
      }
      if(*year1 % 4 != 0 && *day1 > 28)
      {
        printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
        fail += 1;
      }
    }
    if(fail > 0)
      continue;
    else
      break;
  }

  for(;;)
  {
    int fail = 0;
    printf("Enter second date: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", month2, day2, year2);
    if(*month2 < 1 || *month2 > 12)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for month.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*day2 < 1 || *day2 > 31)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for day.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*year2 < 1)
    {
      printf("Invalid entry for year.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if((*month2 == 4||6||9||11) && *day2 > 30)
    {
      printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
      fail += 1;
    }
    if(*month2 == 2)
    {
      if(*year2 % 4 == 0)
      {
        if(*year2 % 100 == 0)
        {
          if(*year2 % 400 == 0 && *day2 > 29)
          {
            printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
            fail += 1;
          }
          if(*year2 % 400 != 0 && *day2 > 28)
          {
            printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
            fail += 1;
          }
        }
        if(*year2 % 100 != 0 && *day2 > 29)
        {
          printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
          fail += 1;
        }
      }
      if(*year2 % 4 != 0 && *day2 > 28)
      {
        printf("Invalid month and day combination.\n");
        fail += 1;
      }
    }
    if(fail > 0)
      continue;
    else
      break;
  }
}

void leap(int year1, int year2, int *leap1, int *leap2)             // Determines if first and final years are leap years
{
  if(year1 % 4 == 0)
  {
    if(year1 % 100 == 0)
    {
      if(year1 % 400 == 0)
        *leap1 = 1;
      else
        *leap1 = 0;
    }
    else
      *leap1 = 1;
  }
  else
    *leap1 = 0;

  if(year2 % 4 == 0)
  {
    if(year2 % 100 == 0)
    {
      if(year2 % 400 == 0)
        *leap2 = 1;
      else
        *leap2 = 0;
    }
    else
      *leap2 = 1;
  }
  else
    *leap2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(month1 == 1||3||5||7||8||10)` In C, this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You have to check each condition by itself, i.e., `if(month == 1 || month == 3 || ...)`.  Also... this is a harder problem than you may realize.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(month1 == 1||3||5||7||8||10)
```

always evaluates to `true`, because it is parsed

```
if ((month == 1) || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10)
```

and any nonzero integer evaluates to `true`. Also, you forgot about December.

Answer (score 0):

You have this construct a lot in your code:

```
value == 1||3||5||7||8||10||12
```

This doesn't do what you think it does in C, you have to write it like this:

```
value == 1 || value == 3 || value == 5 || etc...
```

After you've fixed this and cleaned up your code come back if the problem persists (make a new question though).

Comment: Well... it *works*... just not how the OP would like it to :)

Answer (score 0):

```
i == 3||5||7||8||10||12
```

This condition will always evaulate to `true` becaue `||` cannot be used to distinguish between different cases. It's a logical operator and any value not equal to 0 will evaluate to `true`.

I would suggest you to store the number of days in an array:

```
int daysPerMonth[] = {31,28,31,30 .. };
```

So that you can easily know how many days a month has by doing `daysPerMonth[i]` without so many complex conditions. It will improve readability too.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion.  The program works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (month1 == 1||3||5||7||8||10||12)
```

doesn't quite do what you are thinking it does. What you mean is:

```
if (month1 == 1 || month1 == 3 || month1 == 5 || 
     month1 == 7|| month1 == 8|| month1 == 10|| month1 == 12)
```

What your statement does is evaluate `(month == 1) || 3`. For this, it needs to convert `3` to a boolean value, which means it gets to be `true`, since it isn't zero. As such, the result of the comparison is true, which means that the entire if-clause is true as well (as a matter of fact, laziness means it realizes this right at this point (or earlier if the month actually was `1`) and it doesn't even calculate anything considering the rest of the month numbers.)

As such, the whole if-clause evaluates to `true`. With a whole bunch of these in your code, your code is bound to do some strange things.

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `||`, so your answer is wrong. Check [Daniel Fischer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290024/445517) for what really happens.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You are correct. While the answer you pointed at is more correct, I do find it to be lacking in explanation, so I modified my answer to be as correct and still be as explaining as it was.